# How to make execution speed faster (python opencv)

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a code which devide a image in two part and repeat this action with other images which is in same folder.
However, execution speed is very slowlly. Do you have any idea that the speed make faster?

```
import os
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
files = os.listdir()
os.makedirs('Dist')

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    dst_upper_right = img[0:1620,0:2400]
    dst_upper_right = ndimage.rotate(dst_upper_right,270)
    cv2.imwrite('./Dist/dst_'+file+'_02.jpg',dst_upper_right)

    dst_lower_left = img[1621:3240,0:2400]
    dst_lower_left = ndimage.rotate(dst_lower_left,270)
    cv2.imwrite('./Dist/dst_'+file+'_01.jpg',dst_lower_left)
```

Comment: try to rotate using numpy, [numpy.rot90(m, 3)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) -> 3 for 90*3 = 270. The one you are [using says](http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) that it has some interpolation that for this kind of rotations (divisible by 90 ) you do not need... maybe this is faster

Comment: I sucseed to make this code faster very much! thank you.